# With Spring webflux, does returning a Mono<Foo> cut down on serialization cost compared to returning a fully-realized Foo instance?

Tags: spring-webflux

I am converting my data service to use the MongoDB reactive driver.  With the way that I am querying for information (in several parts, concurrently) it has allowed me to coordinate all of the activities much more efficiently and quickly.

So far, the consumers of this API are not ready to be converted, so I end up calling `Mono.zip(...).blockOptional` before returning the fully realized object to the rest method to return to the client.  But I am wondering if I could benefit from returning a Mono, instead, and still get some benefits, even if the consumers of my data service API are not ready to convert fully to reactive.

Would returning a Mono save on Spring web serialization/deserialization between the two services?  That, currently, is the most expensive portion of the entire data flow.  Or would it be basically the same cost in time and performance between returning a Mono or the object itself?

Yes, I understand the benefit of making the whole data flow entirely reactive, and I agree that is the best way to go.  But, for now, I am trying to learn whether or not I can get the benefit of less serialization before going "full reactive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in serialisation when you return Mono or Foo. There is difference in blocking thread or not.

Simply when you return Mono or flux each IO trip will not block thread but as soon as your data leave your service it will be serialised into json

Also as soon as you call `block()` on reactive api there is no benefits at all.

The main idea of reactive is not to make api faster it is to make your api to handle more. So in case if you have one service fully reactive and other consumers are not then you still have benefits because your service will be able to handle more consumers